# Resetting javascript results for printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with a custom html template I'm designing.  I have a three column layout that runs a bit of javascript that finds the tallest of the three columns, and sets the height of each to the same value so the text decorations match across the screen.

Enter printing, with a dedicated media="print" css I've disabled the floats, and other decorations and just wanted a simple print, but the print view is including the height output from the screen media.  How do I set the height of these sections to auto for the print?

EDIT:

In response to a comment asking for more information I'm using the following javascript to set the height of the 3 columns:

```
matchColumns=function(){
     var divs,contDivs,maxHeight,divHeight,d;
     divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
     contDivs=[];
     maxHeight=0;
     for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
          // make collection with <div> elements with class attribute "equal"
          if(/\bequal\b/.test(divs[i].className)){
                d=divs[i];
                contDivs[contDivs.length]=d;
                if(d.offsetHeight){
                     divHeight=d.offsetHeight;
                }
                else if(d.style.pixelHeight){
                     divHeight=d.style.pixelHeight;
                }
                maxHeight=Math.max(maxHeight,divHeight);
          }
     }
     for(var i=0;i<contDivs.length;i++){
          contDivs[i].style.height=maxHeight + "px";
     }
}
window.onload=function(){
     if(document.getElementsByTagName){
          matchColumns();
     }
}
```

It works by adding a class=equal to a div container so that the script knows which sections it should be working on.

Comment: Can you give more information about how are you setting the height in javascript?, maybe you can use `align-items: stretch;` to set the height of the columns https://cssreference.io/flexbox/#align-items

Comment: I thought about using flexbox model but I couldn't make it work as I wasn't trying to do the whole site in flex, but instead just that section that had the matching column heights